# DefaultAzureCredential, InteractiveBrowserCredential, etc... from JavaScript Azure SDK throws error during compile time due to child_process not found

Tags: javascript, azure, sdk, azure-identity, azure-sdk-js

I am developing a Microsoft 365 / Office 2013 - 2021 Taskpane Add-in using Visual Studio Code that is written in JavaScript.  The meat and potatoes of the add-in work.  It's the sides that are causing trouble.  To elaborate, I find myself stuck trying to implement Azure Single Sign-On and KeyVault access, as I've encountered an error concerning any and every Azure credential type I've attempted to use from `DefaultAzureCredential` to `InteractiveBrowserCredential`.

During compilation, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@azure/identity/dist-esm/src/credentials/azureDeveloperCliCredential.js 5:0-42

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\@azure\identity\dist-esm\src\credentials'
```

Upon examination of azureDeveloperCliCredential.js, line 05 plainly states `import child_process from "child_process";`.  I tried commenting on that line. That results in a myriad of errors during compile time. I also tried setting `child_process` to '`false`' / '`empty`' in the *webpack.config.js* file and the *package.json* file - The dev server will not run the add-in with `child_process` set as such.  I'm aware that certain processes can and can't be spawned from the browser; however, what's causing the error is server-side code that shouldn't be causing errors...right?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After much research here on StackOverflow, the solution was to mark `child_process: "false"` in the `package.json` file located in `.\node_modules\@azure\identity`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug that has been fixed by https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/pull/27097.  The latest version @azure/identity should work.